# run file in browser from vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

just installed vscode and I'm missing a trick which I think should be obvious but I just can't seem to find the answer.

I run apache as my local test server. When I'm in vscode and have a root folder open I would like to be able to send any file I'm editing to my browser and use the root folder name + relative path to file in the url sent to browser.

so what I actually want to send to browser is full url :

http://localhost/current-root-folder-in-vscode/relative-path-to-file

the file could be the open open one or one listed in vscode explorer which is not open.

suggestions much apprceiated.

p.s. I have searched possible vscode extensions and haven't found anything that seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I edited View-In-Browser extension locally to make it work the way I want.